# How to lock JavaScript element on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an new element in Javascript and `appendChild`ed it to an `parentNode` of HTML element, everything seems great, I see it and can put data in it, but when I'm trying to change size of my browser, or scroll it this element is "following me".

How can I "lock" it, so it won't move from the place I put it in?

Thank You everyone for answering. I finally made it! :) I used method wrote by @Abhishek Verma.

Comment: Question not clear enough. It is strongly advised that a diagram should be included.

Comment: where is your code??? which you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can create element and apply following css class.

```
.StaticElement
{
 position: static;
 top: 0:
 left: 250;
}
```

You can change the position of div by changing the value of top an left element in css.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, set the position property value to 'absolute'. This will maintain the position relative to the parent `<div>` no matter how far you scroll through.

```
#yourdiv {
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Edit**

Just make sure your parent div also has a position property value and it is anything other than 'static', or unset.

For more info on CSS positioning, please refer: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

In you css do
    `.parentDiv
    {
     position: fixed;
    }`